# htaccess not works hilfe

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem with this htaccess, can someone help me, as soon as I upload this htaccess, I get a message on the website (500 internal server error).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule (.*\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|js|css|swf))$ webroot/img_handler.php?arg=$1 [L] 
   RewriteRule    ^$ webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# disable directory browsing -IMPORTANT, do NOT remove.
Options -Indexes

# protect the htaccess file
<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

# disable the server signature
ServerSignature Off


# protect php.ini
<files *.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Comment: If you look at Apache's error logs, it should tell you what's wrong. I'm not sure but I suspect the problem is the `<files *.ini>` block. IIRC `<Files>` does not support glob patterns like that.

Comment: I deleted the line with <files *.ini> and <Files>, it still doesn't work. I still get the same error message. 500 internal server error .

Comment: Is there anything useful in Apache's error logs?

Comment: where can I find the apache log error in shared hosting?

Comment: That really depends on how they configured their server. On my shared hosting, error logs are in a "logs" folder when I ssh or ftp into my account, alongside the "public_html" folder. But that's not always the case.

Comment: Oh well the log directory in FTP there is no error log. is empty .